# Como mudar a cor da fonte do titulo do aplicativo

Tags: android

Estou querendo mudar a cor da fonte do titulo do aplicativo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ali aonde está escrito `COMO ESTOU DIRIGINDO?` como fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Android 2.1 e superior**
Se estiver a utilizar a *Support Library* altere o ficheiro ***values/styles.xml*** para ficar assim:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <!-- Esta primeira linha deixe ficar igual à sua -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- Inclua estas duas linhas -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    </style>

    <!-- Inclua este style -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Inclua este style, altere o código para a cor que pretender -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
        parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">

        <!-- Cor vermelha -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF0000</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Para Android 3.0 e superior**(sem *Support Library*)
 Altere o ficheiro ***values/styles.xml*** para ficar assim:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <!-- Esta primeira linha deixe ficar igual à sua -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.Holo">

        <!-- Inclua esta linha -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Inclua este style -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Inclua este style, altere o código para a cor que pretender -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
           parent="@style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">

        <!-- Cor vermelha -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF0000</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

<sub>**Fonte:** [Documentação do Android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomText)</sub>

Comment: e para altera fonte do título?

Comment: @Rodolfo Use `<item name="android:fontFamily">`