# Como alterar fonte do título do app?

Tags: android, android-layout

Quero alterar fonte do titulo do app com fonte uma customizado, a fonte já está na pasta `assets/fonts`.

Comment: Relacionada(ou duplicata):[Como mudar a cor da fonte do titulo do aplicativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69019/como-mudar-a-cor-da-fonte-do-titulo-do-aplicativo?rq=1)

Comment: @diegofm é mudar a fonte não a cor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um dos novos recursos disponibilizados a partir do Android O é a possibilidade de [usar *fonts*](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html#fonts-in-xml) como *resources*.

Agora, além das tradicionais pasta de *resources*, é possível adicionar uma pasta denominada *fonts* dentro da pasta *res*.
Para cada um dos arquivos de fontes colocados nessa pasta são criadas entradas na classe R, permitindo que sejam referenciadas como qualquer outro *resource*, via `@font/myfont` ou `R.font.myfont`.

A utilização deste recurso está disponível a partir da versão 3 do Android Studio e necessita, como mínimo de:

- `compileSdkVersion 26`
- `buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"`
- `minSdkVersion 26` ou `minSdkVersion 14` com *appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2*

Com esta configuração e tendo a sua fonte "customizada" dentro da pasta */res/fonts*, altere o ficheiro *values/styles.xml* conforme descrito nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69048/2541) à pergunta [Como mudar a cor da fonte do titulo do aplicativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69019/2541).

Dentro da declaração do style `MyActionBarTitleText` use

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sua_font</item>
```

para indicar o nome da fonte a utilizar no título da app.

Answer (score 2):

A [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) é uma `ViewGroup`, isso significa que você pode agrupar outras `Views` dentro dela.
Fazendo assim:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#fff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_toolbar_title"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:width="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Feito isso, você precisa remover o atual título da sua `Toolbar`, para não gerar conflitos. Utilize o método: `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean showTitle)`

Ficando assim:

```
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
```

Depois mude a `typeFace` da `TextView` que se encontra na `Toolbar`. Faça isso:

```
// findView
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/font.ttf"); // não esqueça do .ttf

toolbarTitle = (TextView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.app_toolbar_title)
toolbarTitle.setTypeface(tf)
```

---

Se você não quiser utilizar uma outra `View` dentro da `Toolbar`, você pode mudar a fonte dela verificando cada **child** que a **Toolbar** tem, até encontrar uma **TextView**.

Como a Toolbar é uma ViewGroup, isso significa que ela pode conter outras View dentro dela, ou seja, a TextView está lá, mas não podemos acessar diretamente, então fazemos assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mToolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = mToolbar.getChildAt(i)
    if (v instanceof TextView || v instanceof AppCompatTextView)
        addTypeFace(v) break;
}

private void addTypeFace(View v) {
    // createFromAsset...
    v.setTypeface(typeface)
}
```